Error: P1013 | MongoDB database, The provided database string is invalid
While executing below query under vs code terminal:
PS C:\desktop\server> npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "RealPropDB" at "cluster0.kmq4a.mongodb.net"
Applying the following changes:
Error: P1013
The provided database string is invalid. An invalid argument was provided: password must be URL encoded in database URL. Please
refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.

you can get the encoded URL by running this in your browser console encodeURI('your-mongodb-url')

I have navigated to the below path under mongodb and updated the database password without using a special character:

then navigate user to here:

Copy this url into your Database_URL path


if you need special symbols, then they should be encoded

The URL you provided is missing the database reference
MongoDB URL Schema
Log into your MongoDB Atlas account, create a new db if you haven't done so already and update the url to include the appropriate database name.
mongodb://<user>:<pass>@cluster0.<server>.mongodb.net/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
